# What is the correct way to fill Model for UserControl?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, architecture, s#arp-architecture

The question is not about MVC but more about code architecture.

I have a partial view that takes a `CompanyModel`

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<CompanyModel>" %>

<%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Name) %>
<%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Location) %>
```

**CompanyModel**

```
public class CompanyModel
{
     [LocalizedDisplayName("Name", NameResourceType = typeof(Resources.Views.CompanyBackground))]
     public string Name{get;set;}
     [LocalizedDisplayName("Location", NameResourceType = typeof(Resources.Views.CompanyBackground))]
     public string Location{get;set;}

     public CompanyModel()
     {
          var info = Project.GetCompanyInfo();
     }
}
```

`Project.GetCompanyInfo()` is the DAL layer and gets data from the DB using Entity Framework

My question: what is the "nice" and correct way to fill `CompanyModel`?:

**Solution 1**

Create **CompanyBag**

```
public class CompanyBag
{
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public string Location{get;set;}
}
```

and `Project.GetCompanyInfo()` will return the `CompanyBag` and in the .ctor of `CompanyModel` I'll fill the Model.

**Solution 2**

`Project.GetCompanyInfo()` will return `CompanyModel` (and thus no helper class is needed) and I'll fill the `Model` in the .ctor of `CompanyModel`

**Solution 3**

maybe your solution?

**UPDATE:**
I have `LoadController` with Load action and this action is kind of a Factory. It will take list of views and will create them by reflection and then load to the page by `Html.RenderPartial(viewName, viewModel)`. So, `CompanyModel` is just one example of the views and therefore I need each view to be independent.

So my question is: should GetCompanyInfo return a `CompanyBag` or a `CompanyModel` and I'll fill the Model in the .ctor?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, following the question update, here's my updated answer :)

I'm assuming the different Views `LoadController` populates take different types of `ViewModel`, and each `ViewModel` is populated from a different part of the domain model. Here's how I'd tackle that:

Firstly, create each partial View as a strongly-typed subclass of `ViewUserControl<TViewModel>`, so `LoadController` can figure out which `ViewModel` type it needs for each of the Views it is told to create.

Secondly, define an `IViewModelFactory<TViewModel>` interface, and create one implementation for each `ViewModel` type you require; each implementation will know how to create and populate its `ViewModel` type from your domain model.

Finally, `LoadController` would figure out the type of `ViewModel` it needs for each view it's been asked to create, and use the appropriate `IViewModelFactory` to create it.

To avoid unnecessary overhead, `LoadController` could [find all the available `IViewModelFactory` implementations at runtime](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2011/03/23/findingtypesinlocallydeployedassemblies2.aspx), and keep a static store of them against the type of `ViewModel` they create.

So to sum up: I would populate `CompanyViewModel` from a `Company` using a `CompanyViewModelFactory`, I would populate a `UserViewModel` from a `User` using a `UserViewModelFactory`, etc. :)

Comment: sorry I was not here couple days. I'm sorry if I mislead you, but I UPDATED my post. I'll be glad if you'll take a look.

Comment: I've now re-written my answer - the basic gist is the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Enhanced Query Objects to deliver your ViewModel straight to you without having to first get the Full Entity graph?

http://www.yellowfeather.co.uk/2011/03/enhanced-query-objects-with-sharp-architecture/

I realize Chris wrote this for NHibernate, but it should be more than enough to give you and idea of what you could do.

Other than that, I cannot offer anything over what Steve has already said. Please pay careful attention his #2. Could not stress that enough.